# Book involving humans living in a hive with marriages being arranged by a machine

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book or part of a book many years ago. I cannot recall the title, author or anything other than it was about humans (probably) living in a hive.

Marriage was arranged and sealed by a machine stapling yours and your mate's papers together.